# Why is my XSLT simplified stylesheet not working?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML like this

```
<books>
  <details ISBN="107887454323" Author="Lynda Green" Price="$56.00" /> 
   ......
</books>
```

The XSL code looks like this

```
<table>
        <xsl:for-each select="books/details">       
            <tr class="boldFont">
                <td class="paddingLeft18">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@ISBN"/>
                </td>                               
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@Author"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./@Price"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

The values don't show up!  What am I missing in this code?

Comment: Please show a [complete XML input document, a complete XSLT stylesheet and the output you expect from the transformation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Values show up for me

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard We don't know the template match for this `for-each`. So, no way to know if it works or not.

Comment: I don't do the template match, I just call directly

Comment: The code as given looks correct. I can only guess that the context item for xsl:for-each is not the parent of the <books> element.

Comment: Do you mean you are writing a [_simplified stylesheet_](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#simplified-stylesheet)? If so, why?

Comment: @Mathias Müller, you are right, I try to use simplified stylesheet, but somehow it doesn't work!

Comment: _What_ does not work and _why_ are you using a simplified stylesheet?

Comment: The values don't show up.  Because the page code is too long, If a template is used, there are many more lines added on this page.  I try to use less code.

Comment: Using a simplified stylesheet does not save you much typing effort, what it _does_ do is prevent you from understanding XSLT. There aren't _many_ more lines of code. And the code you show is not exactly long yet. So, you shouldn't use a simplified stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a [simplified stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#simplified-stylesheet), as Mathias helpfully identified...

*Be sure to add the `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` namespace prefix and the `xsl:version="1.0"` declarations.*

**This input XML:**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<books>
  <details ISBN="107887454323" Author="Lynda Green" Price="$56.00" /> 
  <details ISBN="107887454324" Author="John Green" Price="$99.00" /> 
</books>
```

**Provided to this XSLT transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsl:version="1.0">
  <xsl:for-each select="books/details">       
    <tr class="boldFont">
      <td class="paddingLeft18">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ISBN"/>
      </td>                               
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Author"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@Price"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

**Will yield the desired output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><table><tr class="boldFont"><td class="paddingLeft18">107887454323</td><td>Lynda Green</td><td>$56.00</td></tr><tr class="boldFont"><td class="paddingLeft18">107887454324</td><td>John Green</td><td>$99.00</td></tr></table>
```

Although you don't see the simplified stylesheet form around here often due to its limitations, simplified stylesheets can be useful where the output is heavily boilerplated but with a few XPath references needed to pull values from the input XML document.  For example, I've seen clients prefer simplified stylesheets for generating XSL-FO.